Unable to invoke a session bean deployed in JBoss 5.1 from a session bean deployed in JBoss EAP 7.4 remotely via JNP
I am trying to invoke a session bean deployed in JBoss 5.1.0.GA from a session bean deployed in JBoss EAP 7.4. Is it something that is possible?
I keep on getting this error below even though I have the class on the classpath:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ejb.EJBObject from [Module "org.jboss.client" from local module loader @5bf0fe62 (finder: local module finder @1e097d59

I tried adding all the necessary libraries that are needed for example jboss-client.jar, jboss-naming.jar, jboss-logging, jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec-2.0.0.Final-redhat-00001 that contains the old EJBObject class and other classes from EJB2.x that are needed to perform remote EJB lookups. All I want to know at this point is if it's something possible or not?
A link to the official documentation suppoting that this is possible would be greatly appreciated as well.
